# OpenCV saturation adjustment gives very bad results

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm experimenting with saturation adjustments in OpenCV. A standard approach to the problem is to convert input image from `BGR(A)` to `HSV` colour space and simply adjust the `S` channel like so:

```
# Convert from BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# We want to increase saturation by 50
value = 50

# Grab saturation channel
saturation = hsv[..., 1]

# Increase saturation by a given value
saturation = cv2.add(saturation, value)

# Clip resulting values to fit within 0 - 255 range
np.clip(saturation, 0, 255)

# Put back adjusted channel into the HSV image
hsv[..., 1] = saturation

# Convert back from HSV to BGR
cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

Below is the input image I am working with and the result of the above operations. You can clearly see that something is terribly off with low frequency areas as well with highlights.

Perhaps there is another approach to solve the problem without producing such blockiness?

P.S
The blockiness is not a result of JPEG compression as the artefact blocks do not fit into the standard JPEGs 8x8 coding units. Also, I've confirmed the problem persists on the lossless PNG as both input and output format.

Before:
[image: HSV Before]

After:
[image: HSV After]

Comment: please provide a lossless PNG. I suspect it was generated from a JPEG at some point, so it will contain compression artefacts. saving lossily compressed data in a lossless format does *not* remove the artefacts.

Comment: note that `cv2.add` already performs saturated math, so the `np.clip` following it does nothing. it certainly *can't do* anything with the arguments you give, if your image dtype is uint8.

Comment: Convert saturation to float, normalize it to 1.0, calculate sqrt, and then normalize to 255 and turn back to uint8. In spite of making cv2.add.

Comment: I would recommend multiplying instead of adding. consider having a gray pixel. its saturation would be 0 and hue would be something arbitrary. simply adding 50 gives that gray pixel saturation (and hue!) it can't have. use multiplication, try a factor of 1.5 or 2 to start.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another approach using black and white version of the picture, it worked best for me:

Just sum the picture with the b/w version with coefficient that give 1 in sum. Alpha is the saturation parameter: alpha = 0 gives b/w picture, higher alpha gives more saturated picture. C++ code example:

```
addWeighted(image, alpha, black_and_white(image), 1 - alpha, 0.0, res);
```